# porque siempre me guarada el ultimo valor con un bucle for

Tags: python

estoy intentando con un bucle for que en 3 iteraciones me guarde lo que por dentrada de pantalla pide

```
for a in range(3):
    conjunto = {input()}
    print(conjunto)
```

y al imprimirlo me guarda la ultima palabra

```
print(conjunto)
```

la ultima palabra

y cuando lo imprimo fuera del for me sale lo ultimo que recibio por pantalla

Comment: el problema es que estás guardando los resultados del for en una sola variable, no en un array o lista, no me manejo en python pero creo que lo qe te dije te puede servir de ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Como te comentan lo que haces en **conjunto** es guardar siempre un solo valor para guardar todos los valores usa un array algo así:

```
valores = []
for a in range(3):
    valores.append({input()})

print(valores)
```

como resultado tendras:

[image: result]

Para mayor referencia te sugiero revisar: [append](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_append.asp)

**Actualización**

Para mejor entendimiento te sugiero usar algo asi:

```
valores = []
for a in range(3):
    numero = input('ingrese un numero:')
    valores.append(numero)

print(valores)
```

**Resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: O, incluso más compacto: `[input() for _ in range(3)]`

Comment: O mas compacto `print([input() for _ in range(3)])` xD